# Find limit at 0 of cosine function with embedded sine

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I'm getting stuck on the following exercise where I have to find the limit as x approaches zero, for this cosine function:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\right)$$

The graph shows that there should be a limit of $-1$ at $0$, but I can't find a nice trigonometric identity that allows me to rewrite this such that the $x^2$ in the denominator disappears.

Any indication on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the [fundamental limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767)

$$\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}=\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^2 \to 1$$

and since $\cos x$ is a continuous function

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\cos\left(\pi\cdot\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\right)=\cos (\pi \cdot 1)=-1$$

Comment: hm I'll check the book once again if they are hinting towards one of those fundamental limits. For some reason I have never seen them before so I assumed that I had to rewrite this limit to a familiar form using trig identities. I see the other answers refer to the same fundamental limit as well.

Comment: @Flame Yes is is really foudamental. Refer to the link I've given for all the details to prove it.

Comment: Found it, there was a full page of it. They disguised it with a $\theta$ instead of an $x$ so my brain wired it to angles :)

Comment: @Flame Well done! This is an excellent reference for that! Bye

Comment: Minor clarification: Do you mean the _fundamental_ limit?

Comment: Yes of course! I fix the typo. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the *continuity* of the cosine function. In particular, its continuity at $x=\pi$.

Let $\displaystyle g(x)=\pi\cdot \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=\pi$ using the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130) that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
and the "multiplication law" of limits.

Now by continuity,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(g(x))=\cos(\lim_{x\to 0}g(x))=\cos(\pi)=-1.
$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} &{}\cos \left( \frac{\pi \sin^2 x}{x^2}  \right)  \\
    &= \cos \left( \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\pi \sin^2 x}{x^2}  \right)  &  &\text{cosine is continuous}  \\
    &= \cos \left( \pi \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}  \right)  &  &\text{constant multiple}  \\
    &= \cos \left( \pi \left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2  \right)  &  &\text{$x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous}  \\
    &= \cos \left( \pi \left(1\right)^2  \right)  &  &\text{trigonometric limit}  \\
    &= -1  \text{.}
\end{align*}

The trigonometric limit used is one of a pair of fundamental limits, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x} = 0$, which are usually found by application of the squeeze theorem.